# React-Native Error "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.onLoginSuccess.bind')"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am following a simple example in react-native to log user in.  I added following code to handle that

```js
onButtonPress() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    this.setState({ error: '', loading: true });

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
    .catch(() => {
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(this.onLoginSucess.bind(this))
      .catch(this.onLoginFail.bind(this));
    });
}

onLoginSuccess() {
    this.setState({
      email: '',
      password: '',
      loading: false,
      error: ''
    });
}

onLoginFail() {
    this.setState({
      error: 'Authentication Failed',
      loading: false
    });
}
```

but I get error `"undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.onLoginSuccess.bind')`"

I am very new to react-native, so please explain.

[image]

Comment: My guess is that `onButtonPress` isn't bound correctly probably because you're using it as an event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annual problem I had is that I misspelled method name.  Instead onLoginSuccess, I called it onLoginSucess

Answer (score 2):

You cannot `bind()` multiple times like that. To `bind()` in place is often and only works with anonymous function.

Do this instead:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onLoginSuccess = this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this);
    this.onLoginFailed = this.onLoginFailed.bind(this);
} 

onButtonPress() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    this.setState({ error: '', loading: true });

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(this.onLoginSuccess)
    .catch(() => {
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(this.onLoginSucess)
      .catch(this.onLoginFail);
    });
}

onLoginSuccess() {
    this.setState({
      email: '',
      password: '',
      loading: false,
      error: ''
    });
}

onLoginFail() {
    this.setState({
      error: 'Authentication Failed',
      loading: false
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Val.  That fixed my issue

Comment: Or use this type to declare a function: onLoginSuccess =() => {Stuff in your function...} . If you handle it that way no "this" binding is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
onButtonPress() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    this.setState({ error: '', loading: true });

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
    .catch(() => {
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(this.onLoginSucess.bind(this))
      .catch(this.onLoginFail.bind(this));
    });
}

onLoginSuccess = () => {
    this.setState({
      email: '',
      password: '',
      loading: false,
      error: ''
    });
}

onLoginFail = () => {
    this.setState({
      error: 'Authentication Failed',
      loading: false
    });
}
```